# Text file to json using JQ command

Tags: json, shell, scripting, jq

I have a text file with data like below:

```
6111119268639|22|65024:3|2000225350|Samsung|ADD|234534643645|REMOVE|5645657|65067:3|Apple|ADD|234534643645|REMOVE|3432523|65023:3
6111119268639|22|65024:3|2000225350|Apple|ADD|234534643645|REMOVE|3432523|65023:3
6111119268639|22|65024:3|2000225350|Samsung|ADD|234534643645|REMOVE|3432523|65023:3
```

and so on ...

I want want json output like this below:

```
[{
    "ExternalId": "6111119268639",
    "ExternalIdType": "22",
    "RPPI": "65024:3",
    "NewPrimaryOfferId": "2000225350",
    "Samsung": [{
            "Action": "ADD",
            "NewSecondaryOfferId": "234534643645"
        },
        {
            "Action": "REMOVE",
            "SecondaryProductOfferId": "5645657",
            "RemoveSecondaryProductInstance": "65067:3"
        }
    ],
    "Apple": [
    {
            "Action": "ADD",
            "NewComponentOfferId": "234534643645"
        },
        {
            "Action": "REMOVE",
            "ComponentOfferId": "3432523",
            "RemoveAddOnProductInstance": "65023:3"
        }
    ]
}, 
{
    "ExternalId": "6111119268639",
    "ExternalIdType": "22",
    "RPPI": "65024:3",
    "NewPrimaryOfferId": "2000225350",
    "Apple": [{
            "Action": "ADD",
            "NewComponentOfferId": "234534643645"
        },
        {
            "Action": "REMOVE",
            "ComponentOfferId": "3432523",
            "RemoveAddOnProductInstance": "65023:3"
        }
    ]
}, 
{
    "ExternalId": "6111119268639",
    "ExternalIdType": "22",
    "RPPI": "65024:3",
    "NewPrimaryOfferId": "2000225350",
    "Apple": [{
            "Action": "Samsung",
            "NewComponentOfferId": "234534643645"
        },
        {
            "Action": "REMOVE",
            "ComponentOfferId": "3432523",
            "RemoveAddOnProductInstance": "65023:3"
        }
    ]
}
]
```

Here **ExternalId,ExternalIdType,RPPI,NewPrimaryOfferId** are constant and will be there in every line.But **Samsung** and **Apple** can vary accordingly means there could be only '**Samsung**' in one line or there could be only **'Apple'** in one line or there could be **both** as shown in sample text.

I have written a Jq command for this like below:

```
jq -Rn '[inputs / "|" | [[
  
  ["ExternalId"],["ExternalIdType"],["RPPI"],["NewPrimaryOfferId"],
  (("Samsung", "Apple") as $p |
    [$p, 0] + (["Action"], ["NewSecondaryOfferId"]),
    [$p, 1] + (["Action"], ["SecondaryProductOfferId"], ["RemoveSecondaryProductInstance"])
    )

],.] | transpose | reduce .[] as $k ({}; setpath($k[0];$k[1]))]' data.txt
```

But seems like it is not giving me the desired output I want.Please suggest how can I write the jq command for this using if-else condition for products or any shell script to get the desired json output.Thanks in advance!

Comment: Probably easier to do in perl, python, or whatever other scripting language you prefer.

Comment: It's unclear, what makes the next field following `"Action": "ADD"` be called either `"NewComponentOfferId"` or `"NewSecondaryOfferId"`. Same goes for the fields after `"Action": "REMOVE"`: Sometimes it's `"ComponentOfferId"` and `"RemoveAddOnProductInstance"`, sometimes `"SecondaryProductOfferId"` and `"RemoveSecondaryProductInstance"`.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

```
jq -Rn '
  [
    inputs / "|" | reduce (.[4:] | while(. != [];.[6:])) as $prod (
      .[:4] | with_entries(.key |= ["ExternalId","ExternalIdType","RPPI","NewPrimaryOfferId"][.]);
      .[$prod[0]] = [
        {Action:"ADD", NewComponentOfferId:$prod[2]},
        {Action:"REMOVE", ComponentOfferId:$prod[4], RemoveAddOnProductInstance:$prod[5]}
      ]
    )
  ]
' data.txt
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/SfG7bQ_8cI)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work on your test data:

```sh
jq -nR '
   def offer:
     . as $data |
     [[], 0] | until([$data[.[1]]] | inside(["ADD", "REMOVE"]) | not;
       if $data[.[1]] == "ADD" then
        [ .[0] + [{ Action: "ADD", NewComponentOfferId: $data[.[1] + 1] }], .[1] + 2 ]
       else
        [ .[0] + [{ Action: "REMOVE", ComponentOfferId: $data[.[1] + 1], 
          RemoveAddOnProductInstance: $data[.[1] + 2] }], .[1] + 3 ]
       end);

   def build:
       (. / "|") as $data | ($data | length) as $len |
       [ { ExternalId: $data[0], ExternalIdType: $data[1], RPPI: $data[2],
         NewPrimaryOfferId: $data[3] }, 4 ] |
       until(.[1] >= $len;
             ($data[.[1]+1:] | offer) as $off |
             [ .[0] + { ($data[.[1]]): $off[0] }, .[1] + 1 + $off[1] ]) |
      .[0];

  [ inputs | build ]' data.txt
```

Comment: Modulo sometimes using different names for the keys in the objects, of course.